# “ls” found a file, “cp” cannot find it (cannot stat)

Tags: unix, shell, filenames

I have a file called `guess.cpp`. 
I confirmed its existence with `ls`, but when I try to copy it,
I get a “No such file or directory” error message:

```
~$ ls ~cs252/Assignments/guess 
guess.cpp  yesno.cpp  yesno.h
~$ cp guess.cpp ~/UnixCourse/compileAsst/
cp: cannot stat 'guess.cpp': No such file or directory
```

What is going wrong? 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The computer is not a person; you’re not having a conversation. 
OK; you’ve got a `guess.cpp` file
in your `~cs252/Assignments/guess` directory. 
You might have many `guess.cpp` files scattered throughout your system. 
Which one do you want to copy? 
The computer doesn’t “remember” that it just found the `guess.cpp` file
in your `~cs252/Assignments/guess` directory.

You need to do either

```
$ cp ~cs252/Assignments/guess/guess.cpp ~/UnixCourse/compileAsst/
```

or

```
$ cd ~cs252/Assignments/guess
$ cp guess.cpp ~/UnixCourse/compileAsst/
```